# How to integrate "Commenting" and "Like" functionality in app?

Tags: android, ios, facebook

Need some guidance here. I am from non tech background but curious to know. Can you please just help me understanding, commenting on any post or liking any post - to implement this functionality do we need API or we can implement this via coding also ?

Please see image for further understanding. [Comment and Like option like given in FB](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UmFqu.png)

Your help/guidance will be really appreciating.

Cheers, 
Tanuj

Answer (score 0):

I think your question would better fit in [softwareengineering.stackexchange.com](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/)

To give you some guidance: It depends on your need. If the comments need to be synchronized across all users then you'll need an API to get the count and increment it.

If it's only for the current user, you can save them locally and increment the count there.

Comment: Thanks ahbou. I really appreciate your reply on this. If comments needs to be synchronized across all users , in this case API needs to be paid ? Any paid API available in market ? Or we can develop this API at our own ? Thanks again. :-)

Comment: You can develop a basic version using something like Firebase to store the post ID and the comments and likes count associated with it. If my answer helped, please consider accepting it.

Comment: This answers my question. Thank you for your time. I appreciate your help. How can I mark that answered ? I don't see any option. Can you please tell me ?

Comment: No problem. 
If you don't see the option to mark as accepted or upvote it means your account doesn't have enough reputation yet.